# Read console output of a running python process (script)

Tags: command-line, printing, python

I launched a python script that `print`s out some infos.

Now I'm connected to that machine (Gnu/Linux) via ssh.

Is there any way to read the current output of the running process?

I already know how to grab the pid.

Comment: How did you launch it? The phrasing of your question implies that you have launched it as a background process...

Comment: yes it's a background process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

```
strace -p PID -s 9999 -e write
```

from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58550/how-to-view-the-output-of-a-running-process-in-another-bash-session